# PyMongo map reduce: no such methods exists

Tags: python, mongodb, mapreduce, pymongo

I've tried to use the map_reduce() function on my collection following [these](https://api.mongodb.com/python/2.0/examples/map_reduce.html) instructions. Unfortunately it keeps on telling me:

`TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'map_reduce' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.`

I've tried using the map_reduce and also the mapReduce, has this method been removed? Using Pymongo 3.11.0 with the following code:

```
from bson.code import Code

map = Code("function () {"
        "  emit('races', 1);"
        "}")

reduce = Code("function (key, values) {"
           "  var count = 0;"
           "  values.forEach(function(v) {"
           "    count += v;"
           "  });"
           "  return count;"
           "}")


result = db.races.map_reduce(map, reduce, 'myresults')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the version 4.0.1,it appeared the same mistake.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The `map_reduce` and `inline_map_reduce` methods have been removed from pymongo 4.0. The official documentation suggests using `command()` or `aggravate()` to implement them.